# Dynamic role on hasura

Tags: graphql, jwt, authorization, hasura, role-base-authorization

I need to know that how we can implement dynamic role on hasura.I mean if we have lots of tables and want to have 4 access control per the table (insert, delete, update, select), a one way is that we create 4 roles for each table for example if we had two tables that named users, cars, we would have these roles:

1-add_user

2-delete_user

3-update_user

4-select_user

and

5-add_car

6-delete_car

7-update_car

8-select_car

it is not a efficient way...

please help me to find the best way.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding goes of roles, in your case role will just be `user`. Your tables `users` and `cars` will have permissions assigned to `user` role. So for e.g

> Role `user` will have (insert, delete, update, select) permissions for
> `users` table but can only have (select) permission for `cars` table.

For implementation, you can easily create them in `permission` section of your respective table.

[image]

Let me know if this was helpful to you or if you have any furthur doubts.